# Call fragment method from main activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I am calling fragment method from activity with this code

```
ConversationFragment frgObj;
frgObj.addMessageToList("asd", this);
```

But `addMessageToList` method is calling before oncreateview in fragment.I am defining some variables in oncreateview for use in `addMessageToList` method.So that my app is crashing because I can't use important variables in `addMessageToList` method because it's not defined.

How can I fix it ? I have to run oncreateview then run addMessageToList.

Comment: I am getting nullpointerexception for variables.

Comment: Try creating a method in your Fragment which will return the fragment instance (i.e. initialize your fragment within fragment) from that instance call the desired method of that fragment.

Comment: @AnujSharma can you give an example ?

Comment: @Pravin This is not my question.I can call fragment method like this but oncreateview calling after my method.I don't want this.

Comment: OK means you are calling a method while making FragmentTransaction..?

Comment: @Pravin Yes,I am using fragmenttransaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First do fragmentTransaction of ConversationFragment that means after committing your fragmentTransaction, call 
`getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();` and next call your 
`frgObj.addMessageToList("asd", this);`